# Easier way to get data from the CSV file and substitute data from other tables in columns with foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Anyone can help? All day I can not understand why I get an error.

Error is:

> SqlParameter with ParameterName '@FKTO' is not included in SqlParameterCollection

Maybe there is an easier way to get data from the CSV file and substitute data from other tables in columns with foreign key.

```
private void insertInTab()
{
        try
        {
            sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionMSSQLServer);

            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;

            const string strQueryRechnung = @"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Menge, Einheit, BetragBrutto, Beginn, Ende, tblFkto.IdFKTO AS IdF, tblGeraet.Id_Geraet AS IdG
                                                                FROM tblRechnung, tblFkto, tblGeraet
                                                                WHERE 
                                                                      tblFkto.FKTO = @FKTO
                                                                AND   tblGeraet.Bezeichnung = @Bezeichnung
                                                                AND   Menge = @Menge
                                                                AND   Einheit = @Einheit
                                                                AND   BetragBrutto = @BetragBrutto
                                                                AND   Beginn = @Beginn
                                                                AND   Ende = @Ende) 
                                                               INSERT INTO tblRechnung (Menge, Einheit, BetragBrutto, Beginn, Ende, IdFKTO, IdGeraet) 
                                                               VALUES (@Menge, @Einheit, @BetragBrutto, @Beginn, @Ende, tblFkto.IdFKTO, tblGeraet.Id_Geraet);";


            using (sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(strQueryRechnung, sqlConnection))
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@tblFkto.IdFKTO", SqlDbType.Int);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@blGeraet.Id_Geraet", SqlDbType.Int);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Menge", SqlDbType.Int);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Einheit", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@BetragBrutto", SqlDbType.SmallMoney);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Beginn", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Ende", SqlDbType.DateTime);

                sqlConnection.Open();

                for (int i = 2; i < dgvCSVRechnung.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    sqlCommand.Parameters["@FKTO"].Value = dgvCSVRechnung.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                    sqlCommand.Parameters["@Bezeichnung"].Value = dgvCSVRechnung.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
                    sqlCommand.Parameters["@Menge"].Value = Int32.Parse((string)dgvCSVRechnung.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters["@Einheit"].Value = dgvCSVRechnung.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value;
                    sqlCommand.Parameters["@BetragBrutto"].Value = Decimal.Parse((string)dgvCSVRechnung.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters["@Beginn"].Value = DateTime.ParseExact(dgvCSVRechnung.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString(), "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters["@Ende"].Value = DateTime.ParseExact(dgvCSVRechnung.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString(), "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Fehler!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
}
```

Comment: The parameter you add is called `@tblFkto.IdFKTO` - but you're setting a value for `@FKTO`. The parameter name in the **definition** of the list of parameters, and the one in the code where you set its values, **MUST MATCH**

Comment: but hier i want to pass exectly the value received from the table in the database. (                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@tblFkto.IdFKTO", SqlDbType.Int);
                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@blGeraet.Id_Geraet", SqlDbType.Int);)

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean - first of all, your parameter names should **NOT** contain any dots - those names are just names on their own - they don't refer to a table or anything like that. So it should be `@IdFKTO` and `@Id_Gereat` - nothing else. When you **SET** those values - then you can refer to a table and its column using the dot-notation - but not when you declare/define the parameter

Comment: (When you SET those values - then you can refer to a table and its column using the dot-notation - but not when you declare/define the parameter). Could you show me how it's done using my example. Please